# MySql - Get latest rows from table without duplicate subject id

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to get the latest threads that have been posted on in a Forum with vars from Users, Threads and the last Post.  Problem is that the current method i am attempting brings back duplicate threads because the newer posts have been posted in those threads, whereas i just want one post to return per thread, not all the latest posts.

```
SELECT t.thread_id, u.user_name, p.post_entry
FROM forum_thread as t
LEFT JOIN forum_post AS p ON p.post_thread = t.thread_id
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = p.post_user
ORDER BY t.thread_lastpost DESC LIMIT 0,8
```

Currently that is returning:

```
/-----------------------------------------/
| 7049 | USERNAME | Post Entry |
|----------------------------------------|
| 7049 | USERNAME | Post Entry | 
|----------------------------------------|
| 7049 | USERNAME | Post Entry | 
|----------------------------------------|
| 7049 | USERNAME | Post Entry | 
|----------------------------------------|
| 7650 | USERNAME | Post Entry | 
|----------------------------------------|
| 7068 | USERNAME | Post Entry | 
|----------------------------------------|
| 7056 | USERNAME | Post Entry | 
|----------------------------------------|
| 7136 | USERNAME | Post Entry |
```

I want to remove those first duplicate IDs and only leave one with the latest post entry from that thread.

I hope i have explained it well enough for people to understand.

Thanks.

-----------------  EDIT --------------------

Got it to work with GROUP BY:

> ```
> SELECT t.thread_id, u.user_id, p.post_entry
> FROM forum_post AS p
> LEFT JOIN forum_thread AS t ON t.thread_id = p.post_thread
> LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = p.post_user
> GROUP BY t.thread_id
> ORDER BY t.thread_lastpost DESC LIMIT 0,8
> ```

Comment: Not sure, but i think that you can solve this using GROUP BY sql statement, grouping by username, ordering by insertion id, and then getting just the first one in each group. Sorry but I can't do the right query to help you right now.

Comment: try using SELECT DISTINCT t.thread_id - the DISTINCT keyword being the important part here.

Comment: I got it working with GROUP BY, but wondering what would be better performance, that or DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

this query may not be best performing, but I can't do much more without knowing structure of your database. You'll need some post_id or post_timestamp for including the second left join as well. Neither DISTINCT nor GROUP BY would solve your issue, as the username and post_entry will usually be different in all cases, i.e. the lines won't actually be distinct.

```
SELECT t.thread_id, u.user_name, p.post_entry
FROM forum_thread as t
LEFT JOIN forum_post AS p ON p.post_thread = t.thread_id
LEFT JOIN forum_post AS p2 ON p.post_id > p2.post_id
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.user_id = p.post_user
where p2.post_id is null
ORDER BY t.thread_lastpost DESC LIMIT 0,8
```

Comment: The original one you posted worked, i figured it out just before you posted.  thread_id and post_thread were the exact same thing, just in the different tables, so using group by on either one managed to get it to return how i wanted them to.